# How to search in a multi-indexed MySQL Database using a non-indexed column

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Given a table called Bugs with the columns (id, token, title, category, device, reported_at, created_at, updated_at).

indexes(category, token, reported_at).

I am required to find how many bugs were created on 2019-03-01 or later.

Any ideas?

Comment: *indexes(category, token, reported_at).* Dores this means three separate single-column indices or one composite index? Provide complete CREATE TABLE instead of your approximate and partial description.

Comment: *I am required to find how many bugs were created on 2019-03-01 or later.* The task is not relative to indices presence.

Comment: Not sure what this has got to do with indices? This is a trivially simple SQL query, so what issue are you facing? You need to show what you’ve managed to write for yourself and ask a question about a specific issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM bugs
    WHERE reported_at reported_at >= '2019-03-01';
```

Indexing is a performance issue.  Without a suitable index, the query will have to check every row.  If there are 1K rows, it will be "fast enough".  If there are a billion rows, it will work, but it will be "painfully slow".

"indexes(category, token, reported_at)." is ambiguous.  What did you mean?

Did you mean that there is a "composite" index like

```
INDEX(category, token, reported_at)
```

That would be especially useful if the `WHERE` clause filters on `category` and perhaps the other two columns.

For your `SELECT`, the Optimizer is likely to use this 3-column index, but because it is "covering".  That is, all the columns in the `SELECT` are included.  (Namely, just `reported_at`.)  "Covering" provides a small performance benefit because it does not have to look both in the Index's BTree and the data's BTree.

Or did you mean that there are 3 single-column indexes:

```
INDEX(category),
INDEX(token),
INDEX(reported_at)
```

In this case, the Optimizer would use that last index because it will make your query more efficient.

Another note:  2019 looks like you might be scanning most of the table?  If so, the Optimizer *may* choose to ignore any indexes and simply scan the entire table.  (This 'surprises' many novices.  But it is deliberate, and sometimes correctly faster.)